# Inserting variable inside src attribute HTML5 with jQuery using .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, href

I want to **insert a variable inside the source of an iframe** to insert the href of another element using .html. The issue its that there are single and double quotes. I tried but the variable is seen as a string. Which is the correct method to make the JS file read this as a variable?

The specific variable is **videoUrl**.

```
var newsVideoLink = $('.js-item-video-link');
var videoUrl = newsVideoLink.attr('href');

newsVideoLink.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    newsVideoContainer.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        'z-index': '1',
        top: '0',
        left: '0'
    })
    .animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, 150)
    .html('<iframe src=\"videoUrl\"' +
        ' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    newsItemClose.css({
        'z-index': '2',
        top: '-10px',
        right: '-540px',
        'font-size': '1em'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string concatenation:

```
.html('<iframe src="' + videoUrl '" +
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string up for the iframe:

```
var newsVideoLink = $('.js-item-video-link');
var videoUrl = newsVideoLink.attr('href');

newsVideoLink.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    newsVideoContainer.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        'z-index': '1',
        top: '0',
        left: '0'
    })
    .animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, 150)
    .html('<iframe src=\"' + videoUrl + '\"' +
            ' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    newsItemClose.css({
        'z-index': '2',
        top: '-10px',
        right: '-540px',
        'font-size': '1em'
    });
});
```

Try this.